# YL620 VFD terminal strip is small - wires are big. Connector options?

Tags: vfd, power-connector

I'm attaching input power (240V single phase) and motor load (3-phase, variable frequency) wires to a terminal strip of a Variable Frequency Drive controller (YL-620).

[image: terminal strip illustration]

The power rating for the device is 2.2 kW (about 9.6 amp draw).  I intend to use regular Romex 14/2wg for the supply power, and use SOOW flexible 14/4 (includes ground) stranded wire cable for the load.

I can connect the solid supply wires under the terminal screws.  But the spacing of the terminal strip is too narrow for typical crimp-on ring or spade connectors for stranded wire.  What's a simple and safe way to connect stranded wires to the small terminal strip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Cu stranded wire with max wire count (makes it flexible and less stress on terminals). For a given X amp rating, per Code, Cu AWG is what it is, therefore the insulation makes them differ in size, max current capacity, etc., i.e., more like solid Cu wire suspended in free air. Bare and in free air is about as small as it gets using Cu.

*Something not recommended but I have used at times ... carefully trimming off some wire strands at the terminal block itself allowing it to fit better under/in terminal screw. Of course, distance of the conductor is huge, however the strands you trimmed off were are already at terminal location. Practically speaking, the current carrying capacity of that circuit was not derated (much). So maybe a larger conductor could be used if required.*

Hope this helps. Be safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a solid AWG 14 wire onto the motor terminals, you cold use four (3 phase + ground) short pieces of solid building wire (e.g. XHHW, THHN) and four insulated crimp-on butt splices to connect to the SOOW.

Is the installation going to be temporary/portable?  (I suspect it is because of the SOOW.)  If so, make sure to solidly attach the SOOW with a strain relief so the splices or screw terminals aren't accidentally pulled out.

If this is a permanent/fixed installation, you should reconsider all the wiring methods, and consider putting the VFD inside an enclosure of some sort.

Comment: I don't think that crimp-on butt splices are better suited for solid wire than than typical VFD terminals are suited for stranded wire. The VFD manual should state the type and size wire that the terminals are suited for.

Comment: In photos that I found, the terminal screws seem to have squarish plates under them that would make them suitable as compression terminals for stranded wire. The manual that I found was not helpful.

Comment: C.Cowie The manual is pretty sparse and doesn’t address wire gauge or connector type. But you’re right that the terminal strip has compression plates. So I think your suggestion is the way to go: use stranded wire under the compression plate and skip any crimp on connector. Good analysis, thanks!

Comment: Theodore: good points about strain relief on any solution. I need cable flexibility because the motor pivots 90 degrees. I’m not keen on crimping onto a solid wire, so I like CCowie’s suggestion better. Thanks!